# Tutorial needed for creating certs with OppenSSL and importing into Glassfish 3.1

Tags: glassfish, openssl, certificate

I have been tasked with using OpenSSL to create certificates for a webservices project and then importing the certs into glassfish 3.1. I do NOT have access to Apache. (The application that is being created works with username/password verification but we want to add in certificates)

I have googled and read many tutorials, but have yet to get certs working. Does anyone know of the quintessential tutorial to point me to?

I have created the CA, CSR and CRTs using OpenSSL and have tried many ways to get them imported into Glassfish's keystore, but the closest to success I have gotten is the following log message

> [#|2012-09-21T16:14:05.859-0500|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|GRIZZLY0007: SSL support could not be configured!
>   java.io.IOException: SSL configuration is invalid due to No available certificate or key corresponds to the SSL cipher suites which are enabled.